# Window closes before I get to "then:" clause while using withNewWindow()

Tags: functional-testing, geb

We are using Geb for our functional tests. In our app, clicking a link opens a new window. Inside our "when:" clause, we are able to use withNewWindow() to click the link and open the new window, and make a few quick assertions. The problem is that we want to make more assertions and do more things within the "then:" clause, but our window closes before we can get there.

```
when: "I navigate to the link"
        JQInstaller jq = new JQInstaller()
        jq.installJQ(browser)
        homeTab.jquery.mouseover()
        report "Mouse Over1"
        waitFor {HealthPageLink.present}
        withNewWindow({HealthPageLink.click() },{
            assert (title.toString() == 'Patient Financing Portal')
            at LoginPage
            report "Login Page"
        }
    )

   then:  "I am at the Login Page"
       at LoginPage
       report "Login Page"
```

In the then: clause, "LoginPage" comes out null, because our new window has been closed after the "when:" clause.

How do we keep this window context open to run some more tests on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Geb will close the window opened using `withNewWindow()`. You can suppress this default behaviour using [`close` option](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/browser.html#passing_options_when_working_with_newly_opened_windows):

```
withNewWindow(close: false, { HealthPageLink.click() }) {
    ...
}
```

The window won't be closed but you will be outside of its context in `then:` block. You can use [`withWindow()'](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/browser.html#switching_context_to_already_opened_windows) for getting back into its context.

```
withWindow({ title.toString() == 'Patient Financing Portal }) {
    ...
}
```

You might actually consider not using `withNewWindow()` in the first place in your `when:` block but simply clicking the health page link and using `withWindow()` in the `then:` block where you would perform all the necessary assertions.

**EDIT**: This isn't documented anywhere but after leaving the context of `withNewWindow()` (and `withWindow()` as well) the page is switched back to the original one. You can use `page` option to switch it back to `LoginPage`:

```
withWindow({ title.toString() == 'Patient Financing Portal }, page: LoginPage) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, but it seems like it has caveats. We are having to add all our properties (fields, etc) onto the previous page model, and not the new one that pops up. The errors show that for some reason it still thinks that it is in the other window's context. Do you know why this is?

Comment: It's not documented anywhere, but `withNewWindow()` and `withWindow()` switch back the page to the one used outside of the closure passed into them. I created an [issue for that](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-279). I also edited my response to cater for that.